# How to avoid duplicating data after refreshing JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

After submitting a form, the data are sent to a servlet and stored in the database. T
Then i use a `request.getRequestDispatcher("CTN/ListPage.jsp").forward(request, response);` to list the data on ListPage.jsp page but if I refresh that same page, the browser tell me that the data will be resent again in a warning message and then, the last stored data is duplicated,..
this seems to  be a common problem after lot of search. So I try the RPG solution by changing:

`request.getRequestDispatcher("CTN/ListPage.jsp").forward(request, response);` to

`response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "CTN/ListPage.jsp");` but I get a 404 error ... *The requested resource () is not available.*

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE:** Servlet code:

```
package com.CTN.controller;

import com.CTN.dao.MatiereDaoLocal;
import com.CTN.dao.SeanceDaoLocal;
import com.CTN.dao.SemestreDaoLocal;
import com.CTN.model.Matiere;
import com.CTN.model.Seance;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author WORK
 */
@WebServlet(name = "NewSeanceAjouterServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewSeanceAjouterServlet"})
public class NewSeanceAjouterServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @EJB
    private MatiereDaoLocal MatiereDao;
    @EJB
    private SeanceDaoLocal SeanceDao;
    @EJB
    private SemestreDaoLocal SemestreDao;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        int matiereId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("matiereId"));
        String seanceTitre = request.getParameter("seanceTitre");
        String seanceContenue = request.getParameter("seanceContenue");
        String seanceType = request.getParameter("seanceType");


        Matiere matiere = MatiereDao.getMatiere(matiereId);



        Seance nouveauSeance = new Seance();
        nouveauSeance.setSeanceTitre(seanceTitre);
        nouveauSeance.setSeanceContenue(seanceContenue);
        nouveauSeance.setSeanceType(seanceType);



        nouveauSeance.setMatiere(matiere);
        nouveauSeance.setSeanceTitre(seanceTitre);
        nouveauSeance.setSeanceContenue(seanceContenue);


        SeanceDao.addSeance(nouveauSeance);


        List<Seance> seances = SeanceDao.getAllSeanceByMatiereId(matiereId);
        List<Matiere> matieres = MatiereDao.getAllMatiereBySemestreId(matiere.getSemestre().getSemestreId());



        request.setAttribute("matieres", matieres); 
        request.setAttribute("seances", seances);

        response.sendRedirect("CTN/ListPage.jsp");

    }
```

*JSP Page:*

```
<div class="box">

                <form action="./NewSeanceAjouterServlet" method="POST">

                    <input id="texthidden" type="text" name="matiereId" value="${matiere.matiereId}" readonly="readonly" /> 

                    <p><span>titre</span></p>
                    <p>
                        <textarea name="seanceTitre"class="courstitre" id=""></textarea>
                        <br/> 
                    </p>

                    <div class="ajouter" >

                        <textarea class="courstext" name="seanceContenue"> </textarea> 

                        <select name="seanceType" selected="selected">                            
                            <option value="Cours">Cours</option>  
                            <option value="Voyage d'Etude">Voyage d'Etude</option>  
                            <option value="Devoir">Devoir</option>  
                            <option value="Examen">Examen</option>  
                        </select>

                        <input   class="button" type="submit" name="action" value="AJOUTER" />

                    </div> 
                </form>   
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the user to list page.

It is a best practice to redirect user to a GET URL after POST.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Since sendRedirect accepts relative URL, I don't think you should add the context path to the URL to which you are redirecting.  The error probably is because you are redirecting to a non existing URL.  Try visiting the URL in browser directly and see whether it works.

Comment: I know about the Post/Redirect/Get. but how can I use it?

Comment: When you call this: response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "CTN/ListPage.jsp"), can you check what is the value of request.getContextPath() + "CTN/ListPage.jsp", and check whether it is accessible from the browser?   Try without request.getContextPath() and with "/CTN/ListPage.jsp"

Comment: response.sendRedirect is the way to do it

Comment: Well any data is listed in that case

Comment: You are not getting 404 any more?  What code have you written ListPage.jsp?

Comment: no, i don't get 404 anymore. I update the post with the JSP code.

Comment: If you are not getting 404, then, your code is working fine.  You need to put some code in ListPage.jsp for it show something.  What you have provided in your question is code of servlet.

Comment: Oh yeah... Sorry... I sleept on my computer... Just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is different from what you're doing - this is the Synchronizer Token Pattern. This solution requires you to add a mechanism to identify the first request from the resubmissions.

The idea: Use a hidden token while presenting the request form itself, and use it to flag out the first request from any succeeding requests.

Once the first submit is received, you will receive back that token. Invalidate that token, so that you'll know that any future requests containing that token are repeat requests. With that information, you can stop your processing logic from writing into the database.

The token can be a random number, or the timestamp.

General flow:

1. User hits your URL.
2. It triggers a servlet where you add the token into the session.

   ```
   session.setAttribute("TOKEN", “12345");  // some random number
   ```
3. Redirect your servlet to a JSP (which becomes the request form for the user) and there, prepare the token in a hidden field.

   ```
   <input type=hidden name=TOKEN value="<%= session.getAttribute("TOKEN") %>" />
   ```
4. User submits.
5. You check the TOKEN against that in the session. Then immediately set it to something else.

   ```
   if (tokenFromRequest == tokenFromSession) {
       session.setAttribute("TOKEN", "INVALID"); // or null
       // do your database activities
   } else { 
       // this is a resubmission, do nothing. Simply redirect to display page.
   }
   ```

**PS:** The one you're doing is the Post-Redirect-Get (PRG) Approach, that requires an extra network trip and has a small exposure when the refresh is pressed too fast such that the redirect has not yet been triggered. The solution above addresses both.

Comment: Well I have no idea about how to do that :( . Can you give me an example?

Comment: So from what I understand, the TOKKEN will be randomly generated from the Servlet. Right?

Comment: Yes. If you want it to be simpler: just use a flag of Y or N. Once you receive the first request, set the flag to N into the session. Then you'll know that the next request is a repeat request.

Comment: Well I have just update the post,.... This may be weird but I've never use session. Yes never. that's why I have no idea about the flag stuff... Can you post an example please.